# Android: Source not found error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I am a newbie to android programming. The problem is that whenever I use Intent, eclipse throws an error that source not found. Its not the code, because the thing worked for me earlier.

code is :

```
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),second.class);
startActivity(i);
```

and error is:
Source not found.
the java file "xxxxxxx" has no source attached (xxxxxx is the path of API jar file)

and when i try to run without debug(ctrl+F11), logcat shows this error:
unable to instantiation activity.

plz help

edited:
the rest of the error is,

// Compiled from View.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class android.view.View implements android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$Callback, android.view.KeyEvent$Callback, android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventSource {

// Field descriptor #59 Ljava/lang/String;
  protected static final java.lang.String VIEW_LOG_TAG = "View";

// Field descriptor #63 I
  public static final int NO_ID = -1;

// Field descriptor #63 I
  public static final int VISIBLE = 0;

// Field descriptor #63 I
  public static final int INVISIBLE = 4;

// Field descriptor #63 I
  public static final int GONE = 8;

// Field descriptor #63 I
  public static final int DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW = 524288;

// Field descriptor #63 I
  public static final int DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH = 1048576;
  .......................................................................
..........................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Please include your Second Activity in the `Manifest.xml` File 
Also make sure that the `Second.java` extends Activity or Service.

ThankYou.

Comment: it extends an activity, and it worked before,but not now, i changed eclipse, sdk and adt, and tied a new installation, but error remains

Answer (score 0):

Do you declare your "second.class" in the manifest? 
If this is your problem, you have to add:

```
<activity
          android:name="com.package.name.second.class"
          android:label="@string/app_name">              <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I hope it works